# Where can I find the symbolic symbols of various bipolar, JFET, MOSFET in a *unified* style?

Tags: mosfet, jfet, fet, bipolar

Where can I find the symbolic symbols of various bipolar, JFET, MOSFET in a *unified* style ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper unified symbols are defined by the International IPC standard and also IEEE Standard 315/ANSI Y32.2/CSA Z99 , which are books to buy.  Yet there are a few opinions that reflect some of these in other [answers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/69311/mosfet-symbol-what-is-the-correct-symbol).

IPC symbols are the preferred [solution](https://global.ihs.com/doc_detail.cfm?&document_name=J%2DSTD%2D001%20REDLINE&item_s_key=00670933&item_key_date=820230&). but based on IEEE standards in most cases.

Since India has a free FOI policy, the IEEE std is available *[here](https://www.ee.iitb.ac.in/%7Espilab/Tips/ansii_graphic_symbols_for_electrical_and_electronics_daigrams_1993.pdf)*.

You might also consider this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_symbol#Transistors

But the more complex the schematic for logic reasons you consider simpler symbols, but for realization you want more complex symbols depending on analog nature of presentation.  e.g. Reverse diodes, ESD protection and parasitic ESL, ESR, DCR and perhaps Ciss, Coss.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does it exist also in electronic format, in order to copy/paste symbols, for creating powerpoint courses ? (the indian version is of poor graphical quality)

Comment: Good question, go search

Comment: You might also consider a simulator with tinyurl exports and screen capture schematic.  https://tinyurl.com/ydlccseo Eg

Comment: ok, for MOS, the list is limited though. But it is an interesting idea.