# How to determine which terminal of a MOSFET is source, drain or gate

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, nmos, pmos, source

I am a student and for my next exam, as part of the tasks, I need to identify which terminals (pins) of P and N type mosfet are gate, source and drain. I have an example photo here, but if possible, I would appreciate a more general answer besides solution to this exercise. I've tried searching on Google, but I maybe didn't understand well enough.

Please disregard the pencil markings on the photo for G S D as they are probably wrong.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the symbol terminals on the schematic or the terminals on an actual device?

Comment: @KevinWhite on the schematic.

Comment: Your pencil marks are correct, at least for the two transistors you've marked. The far-left one seems to have some erased marks that I can't make out, though.

Comment: @Hearth how would it be for the far-left? And more importantly, why? Thanks

Comment: Well, how did you get the ones for the other two? Clearly you're doing something right, you just need the confidence to know it's right.

Answer (score 2):

In this kind of diagram, using discrete FETs, source and body (the middle connection, opposite the gate) are almost always connected together (which also implies a body diode.) This leaves gate, which is the 'capacitor', then drain which has no body connection. (Note: there is such a thing as a *4-terminal FET* with separate body connection, and these can be symmetrical.)

For additional emphasis, sometimes the gate has the bend of the 'L' facing source, as is done here. This isn't always the case however, sometimes gate connection is shown connecting to the center of the gate capacitor.

Finally, one other detail: the source, body, and drain have separate 'plates' to the gate. This indicates an *enhancement-mode* FET. Depletion mode shows these 'plates' as one unbroken line.

More here: [MOSFET symbol - what is the correct symbol](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/69311/mosfet-symbol-what-is-the-correct-symbol)

Comment: To clarify, "this kind of diagram" means a schematic using discrete transistors. Diagrams of VLSI MOSFET designs will not necessarily have the source connected to the body.

Comment: Yes, stick diagrams dispense with such details.

Comment: Not stick diagram, VLSI schematic diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal connected with the middle line is always Source 'S' (which also helps determines its channel type. Inward arrow: N- channel, Outward arrow: P-Channel). While the remaining terminal is Drain 'D'.
The individual terminal on opposite side is Gate 'G'.

Comment: What do you mean by "middle line"? You should note that the source and body of a MOSFET are not always connected together, so looking for such a connection is not a reliable way to identify the source.

Comment: Please see MOSFET symbol for reference. @mkdavor needs a general answer for identifying terminals.

Comment: If the OP needs a general reference then your answer does not provide it. You talk about just one way of indicating the terminals and completely ignore the international standards for drawing MOSFETs.

Comment: Let Op decide his/her understanding with the answer with respect to the schematic shown.You can write (or I would rather say copy) your own detailed answer for Op.

Comment: There's no need for me to write an answer. This question has been answered over and over again on this site, as I suggested in my close-as-duplicate vote. My comments were for the benefit of other future readers of your answer, not just the OP.

Comment: Better benefit the future readers by posting your "international standard" answer here rather than extending this thread.

Comment: I provided a link to it in the comments to the question, as did hacktastical.

Comment: Thats great. Well done