# what is the diffrence between 5 VDD and 12V on this pin out diagram

Tags: voltage, schematics, wifi

[image]

I have this wifi module that i pulled from my dishwasher. On the pinout directions it says 5vdd and 12v im confused on what this means. what is the input power that is needed

Comment: It could mean that the board can accept 5V and anything upto 12V due to presence of an onboard regulator. But cannot be said for certain unless you can check if there is a regulator/smps circiut onboard or confirmed by the vendor.

Comment: This does not make much sense to me. Having said that, this question does not really belong here. I recommend contacting LG support or looking for LG forums.

Comment: Unclear. It'll run from 5V or 12V but there may be something you have to do (add a link, remove a resistor, etc) documented elsewhere, to determine which. Best thing would be to measure what the dishwasher supplies. Or contact the dishwasher hacking underground...

Comment: so you guys dont know what the VDD stands for. ive seen vcc before and seen 12v but thats it

Comment: People know where Vdd stands for [check this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17382/what-is-the-difference-between-v-cc-v-dd-v-ee-v-ss). They don't know its *value* in this application.

Comment: Vdd is generally used for a positive supply voltage. d is for drain, as in an N-channel MOSFET. But there is no real standard requiring it to be used in one way or another (the 74HC00 is CMOS but has the supply marked Vcc as in collector for historical reasons) and certainly no standard as to what voltage it might be. So it really tells us very little, except it's positive wrt GND.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like it has a switching power supply and can operate from either 5V or 12V. It's likely it might work okay on other (intermediate) voltages but it's not specified for operation other than at 5.0V+/-10% or 12.0V+/-10%. From the [data](https://fccid.io/ANATEL/02749-16-09946/MANUAL/0CF8BA62-21C3-41EC-B8BB-F505A5369E00/PDF):

[image]

Also:

[image]

That said, I would have a gander at the PCB near the input power connector and switching power supply circuitry to see if there is some kind of jumper or something like that before applying 12V to the module. That's in the upper left of the PCB photo and I see nothing but the photo is quite blurry.

Answer (score 0):

VDD is usally used on CMOS/CMOS variant devices and VCC is usally used on bipolar devices but really they mean the same thing - Positive supply voltage (+).

As for what voltage it may need, it's really not very clear. It could mean it accepts voltages between or at 5-12v or it could mean it operates at either 5v or 12v or something else once again.